# How I get rid of exclamation mark near thread at slack? I cannot find the unsent message

Tags: slack

I get exclamation mark near thread. The point is unsent message but I cannot find it.
When I hover on exclamation mark I can get snippet of the unsent message, but when I search for it, I cannot find it (probably because  it not sent.
This is any solution?

I read twit from slack  - but it not help
https://twitter.com/slackhq/status/1012994511293861894?lang=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, you possibly have an unsent message in this channel. If you hop into the channel, you should be able to resend this message and then this icon will vanish. ✨

Clear Cache

On pc

1. Click the ☰ menu in the top-left corner of Slack.
2. Click "Help".
3. Click "Troubleshooting".
4. Click "Clear Cache & Restart/Exit"